# How can I augment an existing set of syntax rules for a filetype in `vim` without root?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Suppose I wanted to define a new keyword in `C` called `Foo`. I do not have root on the system, so I cannot modify the file `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/c.vim`.

I tried to add the following at the bottom of my `.vimrc`, but it had no effect at all.
In particular, when I edit a file called `Main.c` and write `Foo`, that word is not highlighted the way `int` is.

```
syn keyword cType Foo
```

What is the correct way to augment existing syntax highlighting rules in `vim`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the VIM documentation on how to add to existing syntax.

```
ADDING TO AN EXISTING SYNTAX FILE       *mysyntaxfile-add*

If you are mostly satisfied with an existing syntax file, but would like to
add a few items or change the highlighting, follow these steps:

1. Create your user directory from 'runtimepath', see above.

2. Create a directory in there called "after/syntax".  For Unix:
    mkdir ~/.vim/after
    mkdir ~/.vim/after/syntax

3. Write a Vim script that contains the commands you want to use.  For
   example, to change the colors for the C syntax:
    highlight cComment ctermfg=Green guifg=Green

4. Write that file in the "after/syntax" directory.  Use the name of the
   syntax, with ".vim" added.  For our C syntax:
    :w ~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim

That's it.  The next time you edit a C file the Comment color will be
different.  You don't even have to restart Vim.
```

You can get there by `:help mysyntaxfile-add`

Comment: How in the world did you manage to know the name of that function? :)

Comment: When you are browsing VIM help, the words on the right are keywords that you can use to get there from the command line through `:help`.

Comment: You can also do searches on Vim's help with the `:vimgrep` command. Actually `:help help` is very good starting point that will help you get answers very quickly with Vim's own help.